# Disable file caching on Debian Wheezy Web Server

Tags: linux, apache, caching, nginx, debian

I have a Debian Wheezy server on which I'm running a web server. I have a folder called `data` under my web root directory, which contains several `json` files which get updated infrequently.

Uploading and displaying my files is not an issues. However, if a file is updated or deleted, the webserver still serves up the stale information for the uploaded files, or serves up files that have physically been deleted from the hard drive.

I have tried both Nginx and Apache2 and the problem persists on both, so perhaps it is some form of caching on Debian itself?

Is there a way to only display what is currently in my `data` dir *without* the caching of files?

**VHost config, nginx**

```
server {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        #
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #       fastcgi_index index.php;
        #       include fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

Comment: could you please include the webserver config?

Comment: @John Can you be more specific? The virtual host configuragtion? Or the config for the server itself? Both are rather long. Is there a specific parameter I should be looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring to the vhost config, of course..

Comment: @John updated with the vhost file for my site on my nginx server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the following to your server block

```
location ~* \.(?:json)$ {
   expires -1;
}
```

and restart nginx using `nginx -s reload`

this should disable caching for all `.json` files

Comment: I get the error `[emerg] unexpected "}"` when trying your code block

Comment: Ha yeah I should have caught that myself tbh... anyway, works like a charm! Thanks a lot, bud.

Comment: Actually, it still has stale data, deleted files are no longer accessible, but it seems that it is still caching live files?

Comment: It turns out it updates MUCH faster now, as in under a minute. I'm OK with that